# Can wget detect remote duplicate files (with different names) and download only one?

Tags: wget

I'm retrieving a dynamic website contents recursively.  Unfortunately, files are available from different dynamic URLs.  For instance, maybe file `http://foo.bar/bla.php?q=xyz` and `http://foo.bar/bla.php?q=abc` are **exactly** the same (they have the same checksum) but are downloaded as different files.

Is it possible to make wget detect such a thing and download only one of them?

Plus: Is it possible to make `-k` convert links to the one downloaded, even if pages refer to the second one?

Thanks!